# Cannot run docker container. Error response from daemon pull

Tags: python, bash, docker, machine-learning

To use TensorFlow serving, I had to use docker.

I downloaded the TensorFlow image using

```
docker pull tensorflow/serving
```

After that, I had to start tf serving and map my directories.

```
$ docker run -it -v D:\softwares\software saved file\GITHUB\potato-disease\Plant-disease-classification-using-Convolution-Neural-Networks:/tf_serving -p 8605:8605 --entrypoint /bin/bash tensorflow/serving
```

As a result I have an error :-

```
Unable to find image 'saved:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for saved, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: It is because your volume path contains spaces, put ““ around the path and it should work

Comment: @jayshil It is not a TensorFlow question. The tag may be misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume path contained spaces, putting "" around the path could solve the error

In this case, I changed the name of the directory.

Answered by @ai2ys